# Не работает свойство background-image в IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, css

не работает свойство `background-image` в `IE10`

также пробовал `background`.

Путь правильный, картинка существует. Почему - ума не приложу. В инете ответ не нашёл
В остальных браузерах работает

Стиль:

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:103px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-image:url(img/back.png);
}
```

Comment: попробуйте min-height?

Comment: А через background: url repeat position;?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить "позиционирование" и "повторение" для БГ:

    background: url(img/back.png) 0 0 repeat;

Comment: Задана ли ширина у всех родительских объектов? Проверьте правильный ли путь до картинки генерирует браузер? Если css в отдельной папке, тогда надо `url(..img/bg.png)`

Comment: А у самого блока какой размер? Уверен, что дело не в бекграунде.
Еще не исключаю, что вы используете элемент <header> и не прописали display:block

Comment: А где пример-то?

Answer (score 2):

Подобная проблема может возникнуть если изображение не соответствует своему типу(например переименовали файл и случайно изменили тип с .jpg на .png).

IE, в отличии от других браузеров, не определяет тип изображения, а просто считывает его с названия.

Попробуйте открыть ваше изображение с помощью IE.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в апострофы взять адрес к картинке

Answer (score 0):

А вот так?

```
image:url(img/back.png)
```